# Django - change field validation message

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have an email field in my Newsletter form that looks like this:

```
class NewsletterForm(forms.ModelForm):

    email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={
        'autocomplete': 'off',
        'class': 'form-control',
        'placeholder': _('seuemail@email.com'),
        'required': 'required'
    }))

    class Meta:
        model = Newsletter
        fields = ['email', ]
```

My form is working, but when I type "ahasudah@ahs" without a DOT for the domain name, I get this error "Enter a valid email address"

Where is this?

I just checked the original source and I couldn't find an error message to override like other fields.

https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/fields.py#L523

Any ideas how to override this message?

Comment: I think this is not a django error message. Some browsers (like chrome) check for the input type if you provide `<input type='email'.../>`

Comment: It's django, it comes with "error_messages" array ..

Comment: Can you share your models please??

Answer (score 13):

In fact you can do this in two different ways in two different level:

1. You can do this at the level of the form validation:

```py
class NewsletterForm(forms.ModelForm):

    email = forms.EmailField(
      widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={
        'autocomplete': 'off',
        'class': 'form-control',
        'placeholder': _('seuemail@email.com'),
        'required': 'required'
      }),
      error_messages={'invalid': 'your custom error message'}
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Newsletter
        fields = ['email', ]
```

2. the second way at the level of the model:

2.1. you can do the same as in the form:

```py
    email = models.EmailField(error_messages={'invalid':"you custom error message"})
```

2.2. or you use django [built-in Validators](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/validators/#emailvalidator):

```py
   from django.core.validators import EmailValidator

   email = models.EmailField(validators=[EmailValidator(message="your custom message")]) # in you model class
```

Comment: Multiple of my models inherit from a base model. i.e: `class BaseModel(models.Model)` inherited by `ModelA(BaseModel)`, `ModelB(BaseModel) `I want to apply validator to one field defined in `BaseModel` but only for `ModelA` not `ModelB`. Any suggestions how to do that?

Comment: 2.2 will give two ValidationErrors with different messages (new and old) - specifiying `validators` parameter doesn't override the default ones.