# Django: error_messages is not changing in form

Tags: python, django

I need to change the `error_messages` on a form from english to spanish.

I've found this similar question:

[Django - change field validation message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34445801/django-change-field-validation-message)

And I'm using it's second option 2.1. but It is not working, why?

[image]

```
my_default_errors = {
    'required': 'Este campo es obligatorio',
    'invalid': 'Ese nombre de usuario ya está tomado'
}

class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(label= "Nombre", max_length=100, required=True)
    last_name = forms.CharField(label = 'Apellido', max_length=100, required=True)
    username = forms.CharField(label='Nombre de usuario', max_length=100, required=True, error_messages=my_default_errors)
    email = forms.EmailField(label='Correo electrónico', max_length=60, required=True)
    password1 = forms.CharField(label = 'Contraseña', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Confirmar contraseña', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SignUpForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        for fieldname in ['username', 'password1', 'password2']:
            self.fields[fieldname].help_text = None


    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'email', 'password1',
                 'password2')
```

Answer (score 0):

The docs about [model fields `error_messages`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#error-messages) mention the message key `unique`, but I cannot find any mention of that in the `forms` docs.

Maybe it works for you add this key to your `dict`:

```
my_default_errors = {
    ...
    'unique': 'Ese nombre de usuario ya está tomado',
}
```

Comment: ty. but as you can see in the form: 
Error message keys: required, max_length, min_length, so it does not work