# How to change date format in MinValueValidator error message in Django?

Tags: python, django, validation, django-models, django-forms

I have a field in the model:

```
my_date = models.DateField('my date', validators=[MinValueValidator(date(2021, 1, 14))], null=True)
```

and when my_date is earlier than 2021-1-14 i get message:

```
Ensure this value is greater than or equal to 2021-01-14
```

but i want date in format: "%d.%m.%Y"
so it should be:

```
Ensure this value is greater than or equal to 01.14.2021
```

How to change format of date? maybe in forms.py?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django - change field validation message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34445801/django-change-field-validation-message)

Comment: @May.D: this changes the entire message, but likely we want to keep the translations into place, and only format the `date` differently.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Well OP's question is "how to overwrite error message ?",  so  either it's need editing or closing. Also I guess that this could be solved using django i18n settings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Django will call `str(…)` on the `date` object, hence that result.

What you can do however is make a subclass of `date` where you alter the date formatting:

```
from datetime import date, datetime

class customdate(date):
    def __str__(self):
        return datetime.strftime(self, '%d.%m.%Y')
```

then we can use this for our `MinValueValidator`:

```
my_date = models.DateField(
    'my date',
    validators=[MinValueValidator(customdate(2021, 1, 14))],
    null=True
)
```

This produces as error message:

```
>>> from django.core.validators import MinValueValidator
>>> mvv = MinValueValidator(customdate(2021, 1, 14))
>>> mvv(date(1958, 3, 25))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/djangotest/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/validators.py", line 343, in __call__
    raise ValidationError(self.message, code=self.code, params=params)
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ['Ensure this value is greater than or equal to 14.01.2021.']
```